# How to show Quill Controller text in a Text widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, quill

Whenever I click on the text of Quill Editor, a cursor ('|') appears that generally visible while editing. I don't want the cursor to appear and don't know how to prevent it appearing?

Currently I'm using Quill Editor to show the text of the `QuillController` with `readonly : true`, eg:

```
QuillEditor.basic(
    controller: _controller,
    focusNode: _focusNode,
    autoFocus: false,
    readOnly: true,
),
```

I also tried using `Text()` Widget to show `_controller.document.toPlainText()` but that removes the formatting of the text:

```
Text(
    _controller.document.toPlainText().toString(),
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: regulartextsize,
    ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also faced this issue a long time ago. So... I know there is a simple parameter you can pass to hide the cursor.

First of all, you need to create a quill editor by yourself and then pass values like this example

```
// QuillToolbar.basic(controller: _controller),
QuillEditor(
    controller: _controller,
    scrollController: _scrollController, // ScrollController(),
    scrollable: true,
    focusNode: _focusNode, // FocusNode(canRequestFocus: false),
    autoFocus: false,
    readOnly: true,
    expands: true,
    showCursor: false,    // <--- This is important for hiding the cursor
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
),
```